# jQuery touch swipe effect on li items

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm tring to use jQuery touch swipe to click each li item. this is my html

```
<div class="slider-active" id="active_885">
<label for="slide1-885"></label>
<label for="slide2-885"></label>
<label for="slide3-885"></label>        
</div>
```

this is my script

```
jQuery("#slides_885").swipe({
  swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
  jQuery("#active_885 label:first").click();
  },
  swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
  jQuery("#active_885 label:last").click();
  }
});
```

with my little knowledge in javascript, i could make the above script to click the first label when swipe right and click the last label when swipe left. But what i want is to make the script click the labels (shown in my html above) in order one by one downwards with each swipe to the right and upwards with swipe left.

hope i could explain the point.
any help??

Comment: sorry but i meant the <label>'s :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of your `<label>` items and iterate through that based on swipes.

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-active" id="active_885">
    <label class="swipeLabel" for="slide1-885"></label>
    <label class="swipeLabel" for="slide2-885"></label>
    <label class="swipeLabel" for="slide3-885"></label>        
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var active885Labels = jQuery('label.swipeLabel'),
    current885Label = -1;

jQuery("#slides_885").swipe({
    swipeRight: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                    if (current885Label < active885Labels.length) {
                        current885Label++;
                        active885Labels[current885Label].click()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //we are already at the last label, either wrap around or do nothing, or click the last label again, or do something else
                    }
                },
    swipeLeft: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                    if (current885Label > 0) {
                        current885Label--;
                        active885Labels[current885Label].click()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //we are already at the first label, either wrap around or do nothing, or click the first label again, or do something else
                    }
                }
});
```

Comment: I'll try this and come back to you :D

Comment: where should i define the array? i'm sorry but i don't know a lot in javascript :)